# Why can a system become unresponsive?

Tags: scheduling

I just executed `dot` (a program for drawing directed graphs) with an input file that was so big that it couldn't be rendered in a reasonable amount of time.

My whole system froze. I could barely make it to a text console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to kill `dot`, but it took several minutes.

Why does the system allow something like this? Why does it give a non-critical program such as `dot` 99% of the system and use the remaining 1% for staying responsive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of heavy disk I/O http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5565/whats-the-progress-regarding-improving-system-performance-responsiveness-during and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11/how-can-i-tweak-my-linux-desktop-to-be-more-responsive

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's the way GNU/Linux and other multitasking systems work, they share the processor among the running processes, `dot` won't have 99%, but 100% during 99% of the time. Each process dominates the processor for a certain period of time.

This is handled by schedulers (linux has several schedulers, some just employ the usual strategy, some try to give more time to user interfaces, and so on).

Now, in your case, the problem was — probably — that `dot` wasn't taking a lot of processor time, but lots of memory. And when a program uses too much memory, there is [thrashing](http://enwp.org/thrashing%20%28computer%20science%29), which is exactly a process that makes the system freeze, not because `dot` is doing a lot, but because the kernel has to move memory pages back and forth between the disk (swap partition) and the system memory.

Even if `dot` was just taking 99% of CPU time, chances are that changing to a text terminal would be almost immediate, what happens is that the kernel has to move `dot` stuff out of memory so it can put `X` back in memory so that `X` can see the keys you just hit and move to the text terminal, then the kernel has to move `X` out of memory for `dot` which is still running, and then also move `dot` out to move the text terminal processes (maybe just `login`?) back in memory. (If this looks messy, it's not just because the example is messy — the reality is *this* messy.)

An example is if you log in the text terminal, you may be able to just hit keys, hit backspace, and it will happily happen real-time, but if you do something as simple as running a small tool like `ps`, it will "freeze" for a while because it has to free memory to load `ps` (and it also has to wait in the disk I/O queue, which is being heavily used to move data to and from memory, until it is able to request `ps` from the filesystem).

Comment: Hm, so the way to a better user experience would be to specify certain programs as "*sticky*" and thus prevent those from being swapped out.

Comment: Stickiness hasn't worked like that since the 70s and the original semantics of the ‘sticky’ bit. You *can*, however, lock (parts of) programs into memory so they can't be swapped out. Main memory is an expensive luxury though, so this can't be done for everything.

Comment: @njsg, thanks for the good explanation. A follow-up question: Is there no way to prevent thrashing? I understand that swapping makes memory usage more effective on the whole, but there should be limits. IMHO a process as essential as X should never be moved out of memory. Is there a way to configure a unix-like system such that essential processes are protected from being moved out? On a server its a different thing, but on a desktop I'd rather have a memory-hungry process to crash than to have my desktop stop talking to me.